# Measure resource usage of Docker container on exit

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, cgroups

I create containers which compile/interpret user'c code and pass the result back to the browser (just like JSFiddle). Now, I need to know how much CPU and memory has been used for executing that code. So, I don't need it realtime but on container's exit, so that I can pass these two parameters with the others back to the client.

I tried using [pseudo-files like here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-docker-metrics/), but there is no such a location on my server (Ubuntu 14.04). How I can measure these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

docker has a stats api

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/get-container-stats-based-on-resource-usage

```
 "cpu_usage" : {
           "percpu_usage" : [
              8646879,
              24472255,
              36438778,
              30657443
           ],
```